# Secure access to a private helm repository

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-security

1. Is this even possible with helm?
2. What options for security are possible (BasicAuth? Client Certs? OAuth2?)
3. Is there any example / documentation about this (both server and client side)?

Answer (score 9):

**Helm Private Repository using private GitHub repositories**.

**Steps:**

1. Create a private GitHub repository named `private-helm-registry` or any.
2. Place your Raw Helm Charts.
3. Create a `charts` folder and place `index.yaml` and packaged charts in `.tgz` format inside this folder.
4. Create a GitHub [Personal Access Token](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line/) with read-only access.
5. Add your Repository to helm using the following command:

   ```
   $ helm repo add helm-registry 'https://<git_hub_personal_access_token>@raw.githubusercontent.com/myGitHubAccountName/private-helm-registry/master/charts/'
   "helm-registry" has been added to your repositories
   ```

   **Note:**

   ```
   1. Enclose the Url with single quotes ' '.
   2. The trailing / is mandatory.
   ```
6. To add development or other branches as helm repository, use branch name:

   ```
   $ helm repo add helm-registry-dev 'https://<git_hub_personal_access_token>@raw.githubusercontent.com/myGitHubAccountName/private-helm-registry/<branch>/charts/'
   "helm-registry-dev" has been added to your repositories
   ```

Explore more at: [Using a private github repo as helm chart repo](https://medium.com/@kavehmz/using-a-private-github-repo-as-helm-chart-repo-https-access-95629b2af27c).

Answer (score 4):

If you want a private helm repository, there are not many options today, at least to my knowledge.

- Use internal network where you deploy your repository, so it will be not accessible from the outer world.
- Use helm plugins or write your own.

So basically there are no built-in helm private repositories, but you can achieve required functionality with helm plugins.

Plugin examples:

- [GitHub](https://github.com/technosophos/helm-github) - it is for using GitHub Pages as a chart repository. Not a private repo, but it shows an idea of a plugin, it is very small and simple.
- [Keybase](https://github.com/technosophos/helm-keybase) - similar to GitHub plugin, but stores charts in Keybase instead. Still not private, but can be modified to use keybase `/private` directories.
- [App Registry](https://github.com/app-registry/appr-helm-plugin) - uses app registry (quay.io) to store charts.
- [AWS S3](https://github.com/hypnoglow/helm-s3) - provides a way to use Amazon S3 as a private repo for helm charts. I am the author of this plugin, I wrote it because all options above were not suitable for my purposes.
- [Azure Blob Stoage](https://cwienczek.com/setting-up-secure-helm-chart-repository-on-azure-blob-storage/#comment-5) - This blog post contains a way to use Azure Blob storage as a private repo for helm charts

Comment: what about Jfrog? :(

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean a Helm Repo rather than securing the docker images.

My understanding is that it's just a basic webserver
You could just use GCS or S3 and set up the IAM rules to secure them?